# How to run any component service in publish instance only in AEM/CQ5?

Tags: aem

I want run my service component in PUBLISH mode only, what should i need to add extra things to achieve this.

I have 1 Abc interface class and this is impementation of Abc and i want to run this service component in Publish mode only not in Author mode.

Code:

```
@Service
public class AbcImpl implements AbcService {
    .
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Answer (score 7):

There are several ways to achieve this:

1. Put this service in a different bundle and deploy this bundle only in your publish instances. This will obviously increase deployment complexity.
2. Use the `SlingSettingsService` to determine whether or not the service is running on a publish instance. This option will make your code a little bit uglier and depending on the amount of `public` API your service provides it will add a reasonable amount of code.
3. If the service uses configuration there is a neat little "trick" to set `configurationPolicy = ConfigurationPolicy.REQUIRE` and only provide configuration on those environments you want the service to start on. If you provide configuration only for publish instances but not for author instances the service will only start on publish instances. If your service does not have configuration you could make up "fake" configuration, like adding a "enabled" flag to enable and disable the service.

---

Code example for option 2:

```
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Reference;
import org.apache.sling.settings.SlingSettingsService;

@Component
public class MyService {

    @Reference
    private SlingSettingsService slingSettingsService;

    private boolean isPublish() {
        return this.slingSettingsService.getRunModes().contains("publish");
    }
}
```

You obviously will have to check `isPublish` in every `public` method you expose. On option might be to check this in the `activate` method of your service and throw an exception if `isPublish() == false`. But I am not 100% sure if this works well.

See: [SlingSettingService JavaDoc](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling9/org/apache/sling/settings/SlingSettingsService.html)

Note: As mentioned by user [Abhishek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5153944/abhishek) in the comments, this might be considered a code smell ([Source - Twitter.com](https://twitter.com/joerghoh/status/976496045034213376)).

---

Code example for option 3:

```
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.ConfigurationPolicy;

@Component(configurationPolicy = ConfigurationPolicy.REQUIRE)
public class AbcImpl implements AbcService {
    [...]
}
```

This solution uses OSGi R6 annotations instead of Apache Felix SCR annotations. There should be similar options available for those as well.

See: [ConfigurationPolicy JavaDoc](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r6/cmpn/org/osgi/service/component/annotations/ConfigurationPolicy.html)

Comment: Option 2 appears to be against best practices. https://twitter.com/joerghoh/status/976496045034213376

Comment: @Abhishek Yes. Indeed. That is an excellent point. I personally do not prefer that method as well. In general I try to avoid writing services that should only run on author or publisher all together.